# Why does runBlocking order coroutine execution in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

If I run this code

```
fun main(){
    println("start")
    runBlocking {
        for (i in 0..10){
            launch {
                delay(2000L)
                println(i)
            }
        }
    }
    println("end")
}
```

the output is

```
start
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
end
```

So why are 0 to 10 coroutines ordered? The same code, changed to work with coroutineScope outputs the numbers in random order.

I am just curious about how this works since by the look of it runBlocking still launches the coroutines concurrently

Edit: Rewritten version

```
suspend fun main(){
    println("start")
    coroutineScope {
        for (i in 0..10){
            launch {
                delay(2000L)
                println(i)
            }
        }
    }
    println("end")
}
```

Comment: Could you add how you are changing the code to use coroutineScope? This is going to largely impact the answer.

Comment: `runBlocking` by default has a single-threaded dispatcher, so that's why it's running in sequence. Would have to see how you're using `coroutineScope` to be able to explain how you got it to run out of order.

Comment: coroutineScope as a method in a suspending context, actually allows true parallel execution, like having multiple launches in the same suspending scope. My original understanding was using the Context creation under CoroutineScope(Dispatcher).

Comment: Updated question to include the version rewritten for coroutineScope